# Using mergeProps to access state in mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I need to access state that's been loaded in one dispatch handler from other dispatch handlers. According to [this article](http://enthudrives.com/blog/connect-with-mergeprops/) "where you intend to use properties from store as parameters to dispatch actions, mergeProps is the cleanest choice"

This current container code causes the contained component's required props to not be defined. I'm hoping someone can point out my errors:

```
const mergeProps = (propsFromState, propsFromDispatch) => {
  return {
    onLeave() {
      const topics = propsFromState.topics;
      return propsFromDispatch.onLeaveWithTopics(topics);
    },
    onReceived(args, kwargs, event) {
      const topics = propsFromState.topics;
      return propsFromDispatch.onReceivedWithTopics(args, kwargs, event, topics);
    },
  };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  topics: state.simpl.topics,
  connectionStatus: state.simpl.connectionStatus,
  errors: state.errors,
  progressComponent: optionsWithDefaults.progressComponent,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return ({
...
    onLeaveWithTopics(topics) {
      console.log(`onLeave:: topics: `, topics);
      if (topics) {
        topics.forEach((topic) => {
          dispatch(disconnectedScope(topic));
        });
      }
      return Promise.resolve();
    },
    onReceivedWithTopics(args, kwargs, event, topics) {
      console.log(`onReceived:: args: `, args, `, event: `, event, `, topics: `, topics);
      if (kwargs.error) {
        dispatch(showGenericError(args, kwargs));
      } else {
        const [pk, resourceName, data] = args;
        if (topics) {
          const resolvedTopics = topics.map(
            (topic) => AutobahnReact.Connection.currentConnection.session.resolve(topic)
          );
          resolvedTopics.forEach((topic) => {
            const actions = {
              [`${topic}.add_child`]: addChild,
              [`${topic}.remove_child`]: removeChild,
              [`${topic}.update_child`]: updateScope,
            };
            if (actions[event.topic]) {
              console.log("dispatching: ", actions[event.topic])
              dispatch(actions[event.topic]({ resource_name: resourceName, data, pk }));
            }
          });
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could be wrong here but don't you need to pass other props forward:

```
const mergeProps = (propsFromState, propsFromDispatch) => {
  return {
    ...propsFromState,
    ...propsFromDispatch,
    onLeave() {
      const topics = propsFromState.topics;
      return propsFromDispatch.onLeaveWithTopics(topics);
    },
    onReceived(args, kwargs, event) {
      const topics = propsFromState.topics;
      return propsFromDispatch.onReceivedWithTopics(args, kwargs, event, topics);
    },
  };
};
```